# The Leaflet map floats above all components

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, leaflet

I don't know much about the front-end components of the web. Please point out if there are any deficiencies in the problem description.

I am currently working on an offline map-related business.
*I use tile layers combined with Leaflet.*
The entire page has many other components besides the map layer.
The ideal situation is that the map is at the bottom of the page, with only a part of the center Can operate the map.
As shown below
`pic`[simple demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX8SF.png)
The problem I'm having now is that the map floats on top of all components,
Neither setting z-index nor using pane has any effect.
as shown in the picture
`pic`[initial position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9wOc.png)
[Drag freely on top of all components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDoH1.png)
[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksmZe.gif)
I hope someone can provide me with a solution, or an example, to help me solve this problem, thanks for the guidance.
My brief implementation idea is like this

```
   initOffMap(){
  var that = this
  var latlng = L.latLng(30.584355, 114.298572);
  that.offMap  = L.map('mapContainer', {
      center: [30.584355, 114.298572],
      zoom: that.zoom,
      minZoom: 8,
      maxZoom: 11,
      maxBounds: L.latLngBounds(L.latLng(34.298747907678184,108.30837249755861), L.latLng(28.31487093107572, 116.70742034912111)),
  });
  that.offMap.createPane('labels');
  that.offMap.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = -50;
  var layer = L.tileLayer('http://localhost:8082/hb/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  {
      maxZoom: 11,
      minZoom: 8,
      autoZIndex: false,
      pane: 'labels'
      // zIndex: 111,
  });
  layer.addTo(that.offMap);
  },


<div class="mapContainer" id="mapContainer">
  <div class="head"></div>
  <div class="leftProgressbar"></div>
  <div class="leftcirle"></div>
</div>
```

example
https://plnkr.co/edit/2k8mdrGDLhOQc93L?preview

You can check the above example, I set the background of the header to red, and when you drag the map down, you can clearly see that the map layer floats on the surface and covers the header

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My brief implementation idea is like this

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged `react-leaflet` however that implementation is a regular leaflet implementation. If you do in fact use `react` you should consider using the `react-leaflet` package https://react-leaflet.js.org/
It will probably solve your issue.

The examples in the documentation just show the core implementations, but you will be able to find alot of code here on stackoverflow for whatever you will need.

If you in fact do not use react, update your tags and let me know and I will remove this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, there is an error in my label, thank you for your reminder, but is there any similarity between react and vue, and is there any commonality in the solution to this problem?

Comment: There are some packages made for vue, however I am uncertain they support the latest versions. I don't see any issue of why you could not stick with the official leaflet package. The react version just works as a wrapper package and just makes it easier to work with the map in a `react` way. One common issue is that the leaflet css needed is not included you should be able to find it in the leaflet package`"leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"`. Or you can get it from a hosted service see here `https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/`